# How do I multiply a list with dynamic size depending on user input

Tags: python, string, list, input, multiplication

I want to create a python program that takes as many numbers as the user inputs, puts them in a list, and multiplies them with each other. I want to know how to multiply a list with dynamic size as such. If there are any errors, please let me know.

```
numbs = []
userin = input("Please enter a number, 'q' to stop:")

while userin != 'q':
    numbs2 = float(userin)
    numbs.append(numbs2)
    userin = input("Please enter a number, 'q' to stop:")

while userin == 'q':
```

Comment: It multiplies them by what?  Does it double each number or are you multiplying them by each other?  Why do you say _a list that changes_?  Is it changing within `while userin == 'q'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
>>> product = 1
>>> for num in numbs2:
        product *= num
```

And that's all (no need for the second `while`).

If you're feeling adventurous use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> numbs2 = [5, 7, 8, 3, 2] 
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, numbs2)
1680
```

Comment: You could also use `functools`'s `functools.reduce` like this: `product = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, numbs2)`